# Rails: `includes` a `has_many` relation with `limit`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm using Rails 4.2. I have 3 tables like this:

```
class Collection < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :shares
    has_many :images, through: :shares
    has_many :latest_images, -> { order(created_at: :desc).limit(10) }, class_name: 'Image', through: :shares, source: :image
end

class Share < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :image
    belongs_to :collection
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :shares
    has_many :collections, through: :shares
end
```

My goal is to select some collections and preload the first 10 newest cards of each collection using the `latest_images` relation.

If I do simply:

```
collections = Collection.where(some_condition).includes(:latest_images)
```

The problem is latest_images will contain all cards, not only the last 10 (even if there's a `limit(10)`)

```
collections.first.latest_images.count # => more than 10!!!
```

Instead, if I add the `limit(10)` after loading the collections, I'll have a N+1 query problem:

```
collections.each { |collection| collection.latest_images.limit(10).do_something } # N+1 QUERY
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a note tucked away in the [associations documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) under "Eager loading of associations":

> If you eager load an association with a specified :limit option, it will be ignored, returning all the associated objects.

So, it is behaving as documented even though that might not be the intuitive behaviour.

The work around is to *not* eager load the limited associated and to access separately afterwards. As you point out that's not ideal but it is almost certainly preferable to loading all of the associated objects without a limit.

Comment: So there is no way to eager load that data without load everything and avoid N+1 query?

Comment: No, not using the arel interface I don't think. You could write your own code to do it I guess but you're not going to get it for free unfortunately.